# What is the best location to put templates in django project?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-project-architect

What is the best location to put templates in django project?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the Django book, [chapter 4](http://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter04.html):

> If you can’t think of an obvious place
>   to put your templates, we recommend
>   creating a templates directory within
>   your Django project (i.e., within the
>   mysite directory you created in
>   Chapter 2, if you’ve been following
>   along with our examples).

This is exactly what I do, and has worked great for me.

My directory structure looks something like this:

`/media` for all my CSS/JS/images etc
`/templates` for my templates
`/projectname` for the main project code (i.e. the Python code)

Comment: when you put the templates in /templates, is there a way to tell the template loader to load it without specifying the full path to /template in TEMPLATE_DIRS to load with django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader? It would be great to do this with a relative path, and under 1.4 my loader is not looking under <project>/templates

Answer (score 101):

Placed in `<PROJECT>/<APP>/templates/<APP>/template.html` for app-specific templates to help with making the app reusable elsewhere.

For general "global" templates I put them in `<PROJECT>/templates/template.html`

Comment: Wondering the reason for 2 `<APP>`s in `<PROJECT>/<APP>/templates/<APP>/template.html`?

Comment: The first /app/templates is just to group templates with their relevant app. The second app is to prevent name collisions. (Presumably, you'll point TEMPLATE_DIRS to point to each of these directories, but in the end, Django lumps them together into one giant directory.) See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-subdirectories

Comment: For this to work (django 1.6), I had to add directive for the file system template loader: `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"))`

Comment: This answer is ancient, but somehow I ended up here. For the record, `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is now deprecated - you should instead add `DIRS=[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")]` to `TEMPLATES` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725132/django-cant-find-template-directory

Answer (score 10):

*DJANGO 1.11*

add templates folder where the manage.py exist,which is your base directory.
change the DIRS for TEMPLATES as following in your settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Now to use the template by using the code ,

```
def home(request):
    return render(request,"index.html",{})
```

in views.py.
this works completely fine for django 1.11

Answer (score 9):

Following up from Dominic and dlrust,

We use a setuptools source distribution (sdist) to package our django project and apps to deploy in our different environments.

We have found that the templates and static files need to be under the django application directories so that they can be packaged up by setuptools.

For example, our template and static paths look like:

```
PROJECT/APP/templates/APP/template.html
PROJECT/APP/static/APP/my.js
```

For this to work, the MANIFEST.in needs to be modified (see http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template)

An example of the MANIFEST.in:

```
include setup.py
recursive-include PROJECT *.txt *.html *.js
recursive-include PROJECT *.css *.js *.png *.gif *.bmp *.ico *.jpg *.jpeg
```

Also, you need to confirm in your django settings file that the **app_directories** loader is in your TEMPLATE_LOADERS.  I think it's there by default in django 1.4.

An example of the django settings template loaders:

```
# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Just in case you are wondering why we use sdists instead of just coping rsync files; it's part of our configuration management workflow where we have a single build tarball that is deployed with PIP unchanged into test, acceptance and production environments.

Comment: +1 Thank you for providing the extra detail and example lines.

Comment: +1 smart to include `/static/` in your layout plan when thinking about templates and modular apps. You may want to mention another best practice, putting `css` files in a folder called `static/app/css` likewise for `js` and maybe `jpg` or just `/static/app/images`.

Answer (score 3):

**Django 1.10**

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` is deprecated.

Now we need to use `TEMPLATE`, [introducing in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/#upgrading-templates-to-django-1-8) like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

> Once you have defined TEMPLATES, you can safely remove ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS, TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, TEMPLATE_DEBUG, TEMPLATE_DIRS, TEMPLATE_LOADERS, and TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID.

About the best location, Django looking for template like this :

- **DIRS** defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.
- **APP_DIRS** tells whether the engine should look for templates inside installed applications. Each backend defines a conventional name for the subdirectory inside applications where its templates should be stored.

More information : 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#configuration

Answer (score 1):

This is more a personal choice at the project-level. If you are talking about apps that need to be pluggable, then a templates directory in your app is the place where they go default. But project-wide, it is what works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I understood `TEMPLATE_DIRS` requires an absolute path. And I don't like absolute paths in my code.
So this is working well for me, in `settings.py`:

```
import os

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),
                 "../APPNAME/templates")
)
```

Comment: Django projects have their base path defined already in the standard settings.py as `BASE_DIR`, so you can simplify this to: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../APPNAME/templates')`

Answer (score 1):

`templates` folder just under `django-project` is the best location as shown below because we can more easily manage templates in one place than `templates` folder just under each app folder. You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist#72359515) explaining how to set `templates` folder in detail:

```
django-project
 |-core
 │  |-settings.py
 │  └-urls.py
 |-app1
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 |-app2
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 └-templates # Here
    |-app1
    |  └-a1.html
    └-app2
       └-a2.html
```

Then, so that `templates` folder just under `django-project` can be found, you need to set `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to ["DIRS"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#dirs) in [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates) in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates', # Here
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider having your templates in a database, using [django-dbtemplates](http://bitbucket.org/jezdez/django-dbtemplates/wiki/Home). It is also setup for caching, and the django-reversion application which helps you keep old versions of your templates around.

It works quite well, but I'd prefer a little more flexibility on the import/sync to/from filesystem side.

[edit: 20 Aug 2018 - this repository is no available, one with the same name is available at https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbtemplates and was updated 8 months ago. I no longer use Django in any meaningful way, so can't vouch for this.]

Comment: When would this be a good idea? Isn't it slower to load templates from the DB?

Comment: Dont you become dependent on db if you store templates in db plus will you make your db a part of git commits? How will you coordinate between the changes made by different users in the templates?

Comment: This was written way before I became aware of git. Not even sure I was using svn at the time. I'd recommend using version control systems now.

Comment: @tonemcd, this repository has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Previous solution didn't work in my case. I used:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [ os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),"../myapp/templates") ]
```

Comment: Look my answer. `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is deprecated now.

Comment: Django projects have their base path defined already in the standard settings.py as `BASE_DIR`, so you can simplify this to: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../myapp/templates')`