# Django TemplateDoesNotExist?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My local machine is running Python 2.5 and Nginx on Ubuntu 8.10, with Django builded from latest development trunk.

For every URL I request, it throws:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /appname/path appname/template_name.html
>
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>   * Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.function:
>   * Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.function:
>
> TEMPLATE_DIRS 
>     ('/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates',)

Is it looking for **/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/appname/template_name.html** in this case? The weird thing is this file does existed on disk. Why can't Django locate it?

I run the same application on a remote server with Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 9.04 without such problem. Other settings are the same.

Is there anything misconfigured on my local machine, or what could possibly have caused such errors that I should look into?

In my **settings.py**, I have specified:

```
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# Find templates in the same folder as settings.py.
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

It should be looking for the following files:

- /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/appname1/template1.html
- /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/appname1/template2.html
- /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/appname2/template3.html
- ...

All the above files exist on disk.

**Solved**

It works now after I tried:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/*
```

It's strange. I don't need to do this on the remote server to make it work.

Comment: is your TEMPLATE_DIRS readable by the webserver?

Comment: @Jordan, TEMPLATE_DIRS accessable by root is enough. It's what it's configured on remote server which is working.

Answer (score 267, accepted):

**First solution**:

These settings

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

mean that Django will look at the templates from `templates/` directory under your project.

Assuming your Django project is located at `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/` then with your settings django will look for the templates under `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/`

So in that case we want to move our templates to be structured like this:

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/template1.html
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/template2.html
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates/template3.html
```

**Second solution**:

If that still doesn't work and assuming that you have the apps configured in settings.py like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'appname1',
    'appname2',
    'appname3',
)
```

By default Django will load the templates under `templates/` directory under every installed apps. So with your directory structure, we want to move our templates to be like this:

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/appname1/templates/template1.html
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/appname2/templates/template2.html
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/appname3/templates/template3.html
```

`SETTINGS_PATH` may not be defined by default.  In which case, you will want to define it (in settings.py):

```
import os
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: @jpartogi, I tried both approaches but neither works. I even tried to use absolute path to template in render_to_response() argument but still didn't work.

Comment: Is your django project under `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/`?

Comment: @jpartogi, yes, all installed apps are under /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/appname1, ...

Comment: Can you please edit your original post and paste the settings.py. Excluding the DB Config :-d. Thanks.

Comment: To put every template from different apps in one directory `templates` is not  a good design. But, as I know, after adding your `APP_NAME` in the `settings.py`, `django` might go to search the app's template under the directory which is under the `APP_DIR`. Thus, you can separate the template for various app. (Django 1.7 - .1.9

Comment: Adding project name to `INSTALLED_APP` list solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Is it not /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/appname2/templates/appname2/template2.html

Comment: Django TEMPLATE_DIRSis deprecated since 1.8, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs

Comment: Downvoted because one should *never* be directly manipulating the contents of site-packages. That is for use by your package management system and is subject to being overwritten by automated tools, losing your changes.

Comment: @Alston , is that something that is no longer done with Django after 1.9, because I thought it was?

Answer (score 93):

Find this tuple:

```
    import os
    SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

You need to add to 'DIRS' the string

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

So altogether you need:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: `SETTINGS_PATH` is not actually defined anywhere, so I do not think that this answer will work. Maybe you meant `BASE_DIR`

Comment: define SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Comment: I think Shapon Pal means `SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`, not **file**

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. there are lots of little pieces to orchestrate when setting up django, so this might work for some people but no others. Lots of good solutions in other responses on this post, too!

Answer (score 82):

If you encounter this problem when you add an `app` from scratch. It is probably because that you miss some `settings`. Three steps is needed when adding an `app`.

### 1、Create the directory and template file.

Suppose you have a project named `mysite` and you want to add an `app` named `your_app_name`. Put your template file under `mysite/your_app_name/templates/your_app_name` as following.

```
├── mysite
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── your_app_name
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── your_app_name
│   │       └── my_index.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
```

### 2、Add your `app` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Modify `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'your_app_name',
    ...
]
```

### 3、Add your `app` directory to `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES`.

Modify `settings.py`.

Add os import

```
import os
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app_name', 'templates', 'your_app_name'),
                ...
                ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This was the only solution that works for me using django 2.2.7

Comment: In my case only step 2 was missing. the DIRS array I could leave that empty and it still worked and looked for the template in the right templates directory of the app.

Comment: My app was just missing from the `INSTALLED_APPS ` Thanks!

Comment: This way is working for me. Thanks for the excellent sharing.

Comment: Very well explained, thank you!! This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 15):

In setting .py **remove** TEMPLATE_LOADERS and TEMPLATE DIRS Then **ADD**

```
TEMPLATES = [
 {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['/home/jay/apijay/templates',],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
 },
]
```

Answer (score 12):

I had an embarrassing problem...

I got this error because I was rushing and forgot to put the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`. You would think Django would raise a more descriptive error.

Answer (score 11):

### May, 2023 Update:

`templates` folder can be put just under `django-project` folder or just under each `app` folder as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 │  |-settings.py
 │  └-urls.py
 |-app1
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 |-app2
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 └-templates # Here
    |-app1
    |  └-a1.html
    └-app2
       └-a2.html
```

Or:

```
django-project
 |-core
 │  |-settings.py
 │  └-urls.py
 |-app1
 |  |-urls.py
 |  |-views.py
 |  └-templates # Here
 |     └-app1
 |        └-a1.html
 └-app2
    |-urls.py
    |-views.py
    └-templates # Here
       └-app2
          └-a2.html
```

For example first, you need set `"app1"` and `"app2"` to [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps) in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "app1",
    "app2",
]
```

Then if `templates` folder is just under `django-project` folder as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 │  |-settings.py
 │  └-urls.py
 |-app1
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 |-app2
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 └-templates # Here
    |-app1
    |  └-a1.html
    └-app2
       └-a2.html
```

Then, you need to set `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to ["DIRS"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#dirs) in [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates) in `settings.py` as shown below. *I recommend to put `templates` folder just under `django-project` folder as shown above because you can easily manage templates in one place:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates' # Here
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And, if `templates` folder is just under each `app` folder as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 │  |-settings.py
 │  └-urls.py
 |-app1
 |  |-urls.py
 |  |-views.py
 |  └-templates # Here
 |     └-app1
 |        └-a1.html
 └-app2
    |-urls.py
    |-views.py
    └-templates # Here
       └-app2
          └-a2.html
```

Then, you need to keep `"DIRS"` empty (which is default) without setting `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to `"DIRS"` in `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [], # Keep it empty
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then, define `test()` in `app1/views.py` and `app2/views.py` as shown below. Be careful, you need to set `"app1/a1.html"` and `"app2/a2.html"` instead of just setting `"a1.html"` and `"a2.html"` in [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) as shown below:

```py
# "app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):         # Don't set just "a1.html"
    return render(request, "app1/a1.html")
```

```py
# "app2/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):         # Don't set just "a2.html"
    return render(request, "app2/a2.html")
```

Then, set each `test` view of `app1` and `app2` in `app1/urls.py` and `app2/urls.py` as shown below:

```py
# "app1/urls.py"

from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

app_name = "app1"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.test, name='test'), # Here
]
```

```py
# "app2/urls.py"

from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

app_name = "app2"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.test, name='test'), # Here
]
```

Then, set each `urls.py` of `app1` and `app2` in `core/urls.py` as shown below, then the templates of `app1` and `app2` will be rendered without any errors:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("app1/", include('app1.urls')), # Here
    path("app2/", include('app2.urls'))  # Here
]
```

Lastly again, I recommend to put `templates` folder just under `django-project` folder as shown below because you can easily manage templates in one place:

```
django-project
 |-core
 │  |-settings.py
 │  └-urls.py
 |-app1
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 |-app2
 |  |-urls.py
 |  └-views.py
 └-templates # Here
    |-app1
    |  └-a1.html
    └-app2
       └-a2.html
```

Answer (score 9):

As of Django version tested on version `3`, You need to add your new app to installed app. No other code change is required for a django app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'addyourappnamehere'
]
```

Answer (score 6):

For the django version 1.9,I added

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

line to the Templates block in settings.py
And it worked well

Answer (score 5):

Django `TemplateDoesNotExist` error means simply that the framework can't find the template file.

To use the template-loading API, you'll need to tell the framework where you store your templates. The place to do this is in your settings file (`settings.py`) by `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting. By default it's an empty tuple, so this setting tells Django's template-loading mechanism where to look for templates.

Pick a directory where you'd like to store your templates and add it to TEMPLATE_DIRS e.g.:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
  '/home/django/myproject/templates',
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a hunch, but check out [this article on Django template loading](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types). In particular, make sure you have `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` in your TEMPLATE_LOADERS list.

Comment: This worked for me.   Loads templates from Django apps on the filesystem. For each app in INSTALLED_APPS, the loader looks for a templates subdirectory. If the directory exists, Django looks for templates in there.  <br> TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'APP_DIRS': True,
}]

Answer (score 4):

Check permissions on templates and appname directories, either with ls -l or try doing an absolute path open() from django.

Answer (score 4):

It works now after I tried

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/*
```

It's strange. I dont need to do this on the remote server to make it work.

Also, I have to run the following command on local machine to make all static files accessable but on remote server they are all "root:root".

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/projectname/*
```

Local machine runs on Ubuntu 8.04 desktop edition. Remote server is on Ubuntu 9.04 server edition.

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've added your app to the `project-name/app-namme/settings.py` **INSTALLED_APPS:** .

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['app-name.apps.AppNameConfig']
```

And on  `project-name/app-namme/settings.py` **TEMPLATES:** .

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Answer (score 3):

I must use templates for a internal APP and it works for me:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR + '/THE_APP_NAME', 'templates')],
```

Answer (score 3):

add `rest_framework` to the INSTALLED_APPS if django rest framework. For my case I had missed adding it to the installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    '..........',,
    'rest_framework',
    '.........',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

See which folder django try to load template look at `Template-loader postmortem` in error page, for example, error will sothing like this:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: d:\projects\vcsrc\vcsrc\templates\base.html (Source does not exist)
```

In my error `vcsrc\vcsrc\templates\base.html` not in path.
Then change `TEMPLATES` in `setting.py` file  to your templates path

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {    
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
         # 'DIRS': [], 
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'vcsrc/templates')], 
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

in your **`setting.py`** file replace **`DIRS`** in **`TEMPLATES`** array with this

```
'DIRS': []
```

to this

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

but 1 think u need to know is that 
you have to make a folder with name **`templates`**  and it should on the root path otherwise u have to change the **`DIRS`** value

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was enough just to include my application in **INSTALLED_APPS** in the **settings.py** file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "myapp",
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]
```

Also, remember that the template should be placed in your directory like so:
`myapp/templates/myapp/template_name.html`
but when you point at this template you do this like that:
`template = loader.get_template("myapp/template_name.html")`

Answer (score 1):

**django** was configured to use templates in project_name/app_name/templates/app_name/template.html when referred with render(request, 'app_name/template.html', context)

If you got Template exception the reason is that you hadn't add app_name to installed_apps in settings.

**I had the issue with django 4.1**

Answer (score 0):

Check that your templates.html are in `/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/projectname/templates` dir.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I found a new solution. Actually it is defined in another template so instead of defining TEMPLATE_DIRS yourself, put your directory path name at their:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to admit this, but the problem for me was that a template had been specified as `….hml` instead of `….html`. Watch out!

Answer (score 0):

I added this

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

and it still showed the error, then I realized that in another project the templates was showing without adding that code in settings.py file so I checked that project and I realized that I didn't create a virtual environment in this project so I did

```
virtualenv env
```

and it worked, don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this problem. Here is how I solved this:

Look at your settings.py, locate to `TEMPLATES` variable,
inside the TEMPLATES, add your templates path inside the `DIRS` list. For me, first I set my templates path as `TEMPLATES_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')`, then add `TEMPLATES_PATH` into `DIRS` list, `'DIRS':[TEMPLATES_PATH,]`.
Then restart the server, the TemplateDoesNotExist exception is gone.
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

1.create a folder 'templates' in your 'app'(let say you named such your app) 
and you can put the html file here.
But it s strongly recommended to create a folder with same name('app') in 'templates' folder and only then put htmls there. Into the 'app/templates/app' folder

2.now in 'app' 's urls.py put:

```
  path('', views.index, name='index'), # in case of  use default server index.html
```

3. in  'app' 's views.py put:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 

def index(request): return
    render(request,"app/index.html")
    # name 'index' as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

**Works on Django 3**

I found I believe good way, I have the base.html in root folder, and all other html files in App folders, I
settings.py

```
import os

# This settings are to allow store templates,static and media files in root folder

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

# This is default path from Django, must be added 
#AFTER our BASE_DIR otherwise DB will be broken.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# add your apps to Installed apps
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
    'weblogin',
     ..........
]

# Now add TEMPLATE_DIR to  'DIRS' where in TEMPLATES like bellow
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR, BASE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
# On end of Settings.py put this refferences to Static and Media files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = [MEDIA_DIR,]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

If you have problem with Database, please check if you put the original BASE_DIR bellow the new BASE_DIR otherwise change

```
# Original
'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
# to
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'db.sqlite3'),
```

Django now will be able to find the HTML and Static files both in the App folders and in Root folder without need of adding the name of App folder in front of the file.

```
Struture:
-DjangoProject
    -static(css,JS ...)
    -templates(base.html, ....)
    -other django files like (manage.py, ....)
    -App1
        -templates(index1.html, other html files can extend now base.html too)
        -other App1 files
    -App2
        -templates(index2.html, other html files can extend now base.html too)
        -other App2 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of the "template does not exist" error seems to be forgetting to add the app name in settings.py. I forgot to add it and that was the reason for the error in my case.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I changed the name of my app.  Not surprisingly, Visual Studio did not change the directory name containing the template.  Manually correcting that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in TEMPLATES :

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [r'C:\Users\islam\Desktop\html_project\django\templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

put the full directory of your templates file, then in views :

```
def home(request):
return render(request, "home\index.html")
```

start the path that after templates to the html file

in brief :

the full path is :
**C:\Users\islam\Desktop\html_project\django\templates\home\index.html**

- **C:\Users\islam\Desktop\html_project\django\templates**
  the full path to your template file will be in **TEMPLATES in `'DIRS': ['  ']`**
- **home\index.html** the path that comes after template will be in `render( )`

Answer (score 0):

For those that tried all the options here but still got the error, mine was a simple typo.

My template file was called `"vacation_**list**.html"`, however, my view had a `return render(request, 'vacation_**List**.html')`. Notice the uppercase L in list.

My development box didn't seem to care about case sensitive file names but my production host did, so it couldn't find the file due to the uppercase L.

Answer (score -1):

You should type `'templates'` to DIRS of TEMPLATES in your `settings.py` file.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'], <--- type here!
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: This is not working in my django. that's why -1