# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist at / home.html

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create first site using Django and Udemy tutorial ([here](https://www.udemy.com/learn-django-code-accept-payments-with-stripe/?dtcode=3Rdc8KM2WWhw#/lecture/2222730)) and I stuck on lesson 7: Home view. After runserver i get error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'profiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')

Template Loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/root/Documents/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/    admin/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/root/Documents/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/home.html (File does not exist)



Traceback:
File "/root/Documents/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/ handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request,     *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/Documents/tryDjango/src/profiles/views.py" in home
  7.     return render(request, template, context)
File "/root/Documents/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/root/Documents/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  98.             template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
File "/root/Documents/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  46.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)

   Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
   Exception Value: home.html
```

I created app profiles and my structure tree looks like this:

```
/tryDjango
    /src
        /tryDjango
            urls.py
            setting.py
            _init_.py
            wsgi.py
        /profiles
            admin.py
            models.py
            _init_.py
            tests.py
            views.py  
    /static
        /templates
            home.html
```

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



SECRET_KEY = XXXX

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'profiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tryDjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tryDjango.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static',    'templates'), )
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'profiles.views.home', name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)`
```

I also tried commands from other  and here is the output:

```
>>>from django.conf import settings
>>>print (settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS)
('/root/Documents/tryDjango/static/templates',)

>>> from django.template import loader
>>> print(loader.get_template('home.html'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/Documents/tryDjango/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/    template/loader.py", line 46, in get_template
  raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name)
  django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html
```

Thanks a lot!
P.S I use Debian.

Comment: You are using a mixture of Django 1.7 template settings (TEMPLATE_DIRS) and the new style in 1.8 (TEMPLATES). Choose one style and stick to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django TemplateDoesNotExist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a good idea to put your templates in your `static` because files there will be readily available to the internet, and you probably don't want to be exposing your raw back end to the world `;)`

Try this file structure (note that I have moved the `templates` directory):

```
/tryDjango
    /src
        /tryDjango
            urls.py
            setting.py
            _init_.py
            wsgi.py
            /templates
                home.html 
        /profiles
            admin.py
            models.py
            _init_.py
            tests.py
            views.py
```

Django's [main template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) searches through the directories of each of the `INSTALLED_APPS`, and uses the first template in a `templates` folder that matches.

If you rely upon that (which I recommend), you will need to add `'tryDjango',` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Alternatively, the [other default template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader) will look in paths you have defined for `templates` folders.

For that, you will need to add the full path to [`TEMPLATES['dirs']` in Django 1.8+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings) or [`TEMPLATE_DIRS` in older versions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#template-dirs).

Answer (score 0):

```
1) /templates
      <your app name>folder   
         home.html          

//this is must, create folder and give the name of app.
  in my case,
/studydjango
  /base
     /templates
         /base
            home.html
  /studydjango
  /templates

2) def home(request):
       return render(request, 'base/home.html, context)  // path must given\

3) Include 'your app name' in INSTALLED_APPS
```