# 'TemplateDoesNotExist at /' Error in django?

Tags: python, django

The server is working fine, however while using extend for this 'home.html' file unable to link the template :

In 'home.html':

{ % extends "/template1/personal/header.html" % }
While loading localhost:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

`Using engine django:

1. django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/ffgg/home.html (Source does not exist).
2. django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/ffgg/home.html (Source does not exist)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django TemplateDoesNotExist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist)

Comment: Please post the content of the TEMPLATE_DIRS Variable in your settings.py

Comment: Don't use an absolute path (unless your template is really in that directory, starting from root).

Answer (score 0):

1) Check what is in TEMPLATE_DIRS Variable in settings.py. That is the folder Django looks up in every app in order to find your template.

2) Try remove the leading slash:

`{% extends 'template1/personal/header.html' %}`

3) if template1 is in TEMPLATE_DIRS, then 'app/template.html' would be enough

`{% extends 'personal/header.html' %}`

Read on:

https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/