# TemplateDoesNotExist only happen on prod ec2 but Templates works on local

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2

I have running on my windows pc a django app with following structure

[image]

this app also runs locally and works with this settings

```
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_mysql',
    'users',
    'posts',
    'comments',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',


  #  'chango2.middelware.ProfileCompletionMiddelware',
]

libraries: {
    'tags': 'tags',

}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chango2.urls'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

            ],
        },
    },
]
```

this app work as expected when its runned locally with **python manage.py runserver**

now i trying to deploy this app on a ec2 , i have configurated the security gropus to allow port **80 **and **8000** for inbound and outbound

on ec2 i run with

> (env) ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-242:~$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 chango2.wsgi:application

app starts listening on port 8000 got the first page but for other link
then i recive the 
[image]
the only thing changed between prod and local was 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [**my ec2 dns**]

and DATABASES (but that its working)

Comment: What's inside the templates/users since it's the problem in your case

Comment: @misraX first image updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django TemplateDoesNotExist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist)