# TemplateDoesNotExist even though the file exists

Tags: python, django

[image]

I get this error even though the file exists - why?

[image]

Edit:

[image]

[image]

Additional edit:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from catalog.models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre

def index(request):
    """View function for home page of site."""

    # Generate counts of some of the main objects
    num_books = Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances = BookInstance.objects.all().count()

    # Available books (status = 'a')
    num_instances_available = BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()

    # The 'all()' is implied by default.    
    num_authors = Author.objects.count()

    context = {
        'num_books': num_books,
        'num_instances': num_instances,
        'num_instances_available': num_instances_available,
        'num_authors': num_authors,
    }

    # Render the HTML template index.html with the data in the context variable
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

It says I haven't wrote enough that there's too much code and no description. So I am typing to bypass this error.

Comment: You do not provide enough info(no TEMPLATES settings and no INSTALLED_APPS). But my god feeling that APP_DIRS settings in TEMPLATES is set to False.

Comment: may it help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist#answer-1926354

Comment: Is `catalog` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @AntonPomieshchenko Edited them in

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes.

Comment: Please don't paste images of code, paste your actual code and use the code formatting tool. Please show your view (the one that uses the template). And restart your server, just to be sure. You should remove `catalog/templates` from `DIRS` setting, by the way, that's not necessary since it's an app dir.

Comment: Is permissions of the template directory correct?

Comment: @dirkgroten Done

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks correct, except try not to provide a directory.  That may be the issue.  Here is my setup for one of my projects

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

What could be happening is the `DIRS` file path may not be pointing to where you thing it is.  You can try this in the Django Console

Activate your virtual environment `$ source venv/bin/activate`
Then run `python manage.py shell`

in the shell:

```
>>> from project.settings import TEMPLATES
>>> print(TEMPLATES['DIRS'])
```

Does the output point to where you expect it to?

===== EDIT

I see Django is looking for your template at /catalog/ where in reality, your template actually lives in app/catalog/templates/ so your DIRS directive is not pointing to the correct path.

If you remove the directory in `DIRS`, Django will traverse your catalog directory for a folder called `templates` and find your `index.html`