# Django - TemplateDoesNotExist Error / cant find .html file

Tags: django

django can not find .html file and return TemplateDoesNotExist Error! See image below.

[image: error image]

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html')


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog About</h1>')
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),]
```

**Settings.py**

In setting.py everything is default i only changed one thing in TEMPLATES[]"

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'template')],
```

For more donwload codes rar file:
**https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zg5CN4IyqPtMMyvkru6fUYAQJcbmfX00**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django TemplateDoesNotExist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist)

Comment: Please show the layout of your files in the question, instead of asking users to download your project.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and ran the code. Just change the name of template to templates in settings.py and also change the directory name in blog app. It worked when I did the same[image]