# Template is already exist but template does not exist is showing of user registration

Tags: django

In this Users app, template does not exist showing but template is already exist. I am new in Django.
I have tried so many times but unable to solve this. Please help to solve this.

**Users App:**

**urls.py:**

```
from Users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('register/',user_views.register,name='register'),
path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),name='login'),
path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'),name='logout'),
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import RegisterForm

# Create your views here.
app_name = 'Users'

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Welcome { username }, your account is created')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{'form':form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

app_name = 'Users'

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']
```

**Templates:**
**register.html:**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">SignUp</button>
</form>
```

**login.html:**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

**logout.html:**

```
<h1>You have been logged out</h1>
```

**dashboard app:**
**user_home.html:**

```
<div>
                    {% if users.is_authenticated %}
                        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout </a>
                    {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Login </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
{% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tag }}">
                            {{message}}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
```

**settings.py:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Project: mysite3**
**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include 
from dashboard import views 
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from Users import views as user_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.user_home,name='user_home'),
    path('usermaster/',include(('usermaster.urls','url'), namespace='url')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/',user_views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),name='login'),
    path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'),name='logout'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**usermaster app:**
**urls.py:**

```
from usermaster import views
from django.urls import path


app_name = 'usermaster' 

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home), 
    path('machine_master/',views.index,name='index'),  
    path('addnew',views.addnew),  
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit),  
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update),  
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.destroy),  

]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  
from usermaster.forms import MachineForm  
from usermaster.models import Machine  
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request,'usermaster/home.html')

def addnew(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = MachineForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/')  
            except:  
                pass 
    else:  
        form = MachineForm()  
    return render(request,'usermaster/index.html',{'form':form})

def index(request):  
    machines = Machine.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"usermaster/show.html",{'machines':machines})

def edit(request, id):  
    machine = Machine.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'usermaster/edit.html', {'machine':machine})

def update(request, id):  
    machine = Machine.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = MachineForm(request.POST, instance = machine)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/")  
    return render(request, 'usermaster/edit.html', {'machine': machine})

def destroy(request, id):  
    machine = Machine.objects.get(id=id)  
    machine.delete()  
    return redirect("/")
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Machine(models.Model):  
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    operation_no = models.IntegerField()

  
    class Meta:  
        db_table = "machine"
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms  
from usermaster.models import Machine  
class MachineForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Machine 
        fields = ['machine_name','operation_no'] #https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/
        widgets = { 'machine_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
            'operation_no': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }),
      }
```

**templates:**
**base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
{% load static %}  
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
 </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bootstrapdatatable').DataTable({     
      "aLengthMenu": [[3, 5, 10, 25, -1], [3, 5, 10, 25, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 3
       } 
    );
} );
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

**edit.html:**

```
{% extends 'usermaster/base.html' %}
 
{% block title %}Add New Machine Records{% endblock title %}
 
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-12">
 <form method="post" class="post-form" action="/update/{{machine.id}}">  
   {% csrf_token %}  
  <div class="container">  
 <br>  
  <div class="form-group row">  
  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
  <div class="col-sm-4">  
  <h3>Update Details</h3>  
  </div>  
   </div>  
  <div class="form-group row">  
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Machine Id:</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-4">  
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" id="id_id" required maxlength="20" value="{{ machine.id }}"/>  
  </div>  
   </div>  
   <div class="form-group row">  
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Machine Name:</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-4">  
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="machine_name" id="id_name" required maxlength="100" value="{{ machine.machine_name }}" />  
  </div>  
   </div>  
  <div class="form-group row">  
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Operation number:</label>  
  <div class="col-sm-4">  
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="operation_no" id="id_no" required maxlength="254" value="{{ machine.operation_no }}" />  
  </div>  
   </div>  
  <div class="form-group row">  
  <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
  <div class="col-sm-4">  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button>  
  </div>  
   </div>  
  </div>  
 </form>  
{% endblock content %}
```

**home.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'usermaster/style.css' %}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='dashboard'>
        <div class="dashboard-nav">
            <header><a href="#!" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#"
                                                                                       class="brand-logo"><i
                    class="fas fa-anchor"></i> <span>ASHOK IRON</span></a></header>
            <nav class="dashboard-nav-list"><a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                HOME </a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> MASTER
            </a>
                <a href="{% url 'usermaster:index' %}" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> MACHINE MASTER </a><a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> USERS </a><a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> VIDEOS </a>
              <div class="nav-item-divider"></div>
              <a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class='dashboard-app'>
            <header class='dashboard-toolbar'><a href="#!" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></header>
            <div class='dashboard-content'>
                <div class='container'>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const mobileScreen = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 990px )");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
            $(this).closest(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
                .toggleClass("show")
                .find(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
                .removeClass("show");
            $(this).parent()
                .siblings()
                .removeClass("show");
        });
        $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
            if (mobileScreen.matches) {
                $(".dashboard-nav").toggleClass("mobile-show");
            } else {
                $(".dashboard").toggleClass("dashboard-compact");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

**index.html:**

```
    {% extends 'usermaster/base.html' %}
     
    {% block title %}Add New Machine Records{% endblock title %}
     
    {% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
             
     <form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/addnew">  
       {% csrf_token %}  
      <div class="container">  
     <br>  
      <div class="form-group row">  
      <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">  
      <h3>Enter Machine Details</h3>  
      </div>  
       </div>  
       
       <div class="form-group row">  
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Machine Name:</label>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">  
        {{ form.machine_name }}  
      </div>  
       </div>  
      <div class="form-group row">  
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Operation Number:</label>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">  
        {{ form.operation_no }}  
      </div>  
       </div>  
      <div class="form-group row">  
      <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">  
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>  
      </div>  
       </div>  
      </div>  
     </form>  
    </div> 
    {% endblock content %}

**show.html:**
{% extends 'usermaster/base.html' %} 
{% block title %}Machine Records{% endblock title %}
 
{% block content %}
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>Add New Machine Records</h4> <span><a href="/addnew" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Record</a></span>  
        <div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="bootstrapdatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Machine Name</th>
                <th>Operation Number</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
             </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for machine in machines %}  
    <tr>  
     <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
     <td>{{ machine.id }}</td>  
     <td>{{ machine.machine_name }}</td>  
     <td>{{ machine.operation_no }}</td>   
     <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><a href="/edit/{{ machine.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></p></td>
     <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"><a href="/delete/{{ machine.id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></p></td>  
    </tr>  
   {% endfor %} 
   </tbody>
         
  </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**dashboard app:**
**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def user_home(request):
    return render(request,'dashboard/user_home.html')
```

**templates:**
**user_home.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'usermaster/style.css' %}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='dashboard'>
        <div class="dashboard-nav">
            <header><a href="#!" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#"
                                                                                       class="brand-logo"><i
                    class="fas fa-anchor"></i> <span>ASHOK IRON</span></a></header>
            <nav class="dashboard-nav-list"><a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                HOME </a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> CONTROL PROCESS
            </a>
                <a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> PROCESS SHEET </a><a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>SKILL MATRIX </a><a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> MAINTENANCE </a><a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> SWS </a><a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> SAFETY </a><a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> PFD </a>
              <div class="nav-item-divider"></div>
              <a
                        href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class='dashboard-app'>
            <header class='dashboard-toolbar'><a href="#!" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
                <div>
                    {% if users.is_authenticated %}
                        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout </a>
                    {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Login </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </header>
                {% if messages %}
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tag }}">
                            {{message}}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            <div class='dashboard-content'>
                <div class='container'>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    const mobileScreen = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 990px )");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
            $(this).closest(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
                .toggleClass("show")
                .find(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
                .removeClass("show");
            $(this).parent()
                .siblings()
                .removeClass("show");
        });
        $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
            if (mobileScreen.matches) {
                $(".dashboard-nav").toggleClass("mobile-show");
            } else {
                $(".dashboard").toggleClass("dashboard-compact");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the structure of your project and the exception message you got.

Comment: could you share your settings.py the part where you have the `TEMPLATES` ?

Comment: In the Users app: templates/users/register.html.       Exception message:   django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: users/register.html

Comment: added settings.py

Comment: you have to create a folder called `templates` and inside it creates a folder called `users` and put your files inside the `users`.the `templates` should be in your project not inside the `users` app.if you need more help you can refer to the question's answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1926049/15042684

Comment: no the `templates` should not be inside your Users app but inside your project.i mean that the templates should be in the same folder with Users app(they should be in the same level(hierarchy) ).sorry for my english.

Comment: The folder is already exists inside the Users app.  but again getting error

Comment: raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: users/register.html      This is the error i am getting in the terminal

Comment: could you share your file structures ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240814/discussion-between-thierno-amadou-sow-and-manoj-tolagekar).