# How to override the templates of `django-two-factor-auth` for Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-two-factor-auth

I'm trying to override the templates of [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth) for Django Admin but I don't know how to do it. *I don't have frontend with Django. Instead, I have frontend with `Next.js` and backend with Django.

This is my django project:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  |-admin.py
 |  └-urls.py
 └-templates
```

And, how I set `django-two-factor-auth` following [the doc](https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html) is first, I installed `django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]`:

```
pip install django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]
```

Then, set these apps below to [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps), `OTPMiddleware` to [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-MIDDLEWARE), [LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#login-url) and [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) in `core/settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_otp', # Here
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static', # Here
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp', # Here
    'two_factor' # Here
]

...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware', # Here
    ...
]

LOGIN_URL = 'two_factor:login' # Here

# this one is optional
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'admin:index' # Here

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates',
        ],
        ...
    },
]
```

Then, set the path below to `core/urls.py`:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

...
from two_factor.urls import urlpatterns as tf_urls

urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path('', include(tf_urls)) # Here
]
```

Finally, migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And, this is **Login** page:

```
http://localhost:8000/account/login/
```

[image]

My questions:

1. How can I override the templates of `django-two-factor-auth` for Django Admin?
2. Are there any recommended customizations for the templates of `django-two-factor-auth` for Django Admin?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the templates of [django-two-factor-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/tree/master) for Django Admin by copying [two_factor](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/tree/master/two_factor/templates/two_factor) folder from `two_factor/templates/two_factor/` in your virtual environment to `templates` folder as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  |-admin.py
 |  └-urls.py
 └-templates
    └-two_factor # Here
       |-core
       |  |-backup_tokens.html
       |  |-login.html
       |  |-otp_required.html
       |  |-phone_register.html
       |  |-setup_complete.html
       |  └-setup.html
       |-profile
       |  |-disable.html
       |  └-profile.html
       |-twilio
       |  |-press_a_key.xml
       |  |-sms_message.html
       |  └-token.xml
       |-_base_focus.html
       |-_base.html
       |-_wizard_actions.html
       └-_wizard_forms.html
```

Finally, set `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to [DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#dirs) in [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates) in `settings.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist?noredirect=1&lq=1#72359515) explains how to set Django Templates:

```py
# "settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates', # Here 
        ],
        ...
    },
]
```

In addition, I recommend to modify [_base.html](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/templates/two_factor/_base.html) as shown below to remove `Provide a template named ...` message and to add **Home** button to go to **Home** page in Django Admin:

```
{% "templates/two_factor/_base.html" %}

{% load i18n %} {% <- Add %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body> {% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Remove ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %}
  {% comment %} <div class="alert alert-success"><p class="container">Provide a template named
    <code>two_factor/_base.html</code> to style this page and remove this message.</p></div> {% endcomment %}
       {% ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Remove ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ %}
  {% block content_wrapper %}
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
  {% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Add ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %}
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_staff %}
    <hr>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
          <a class="btn btn-success col-3" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Add ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ %}
</body>
</html>
```

And, I recommend to modify [login.html](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/templates/two_factor/core/login.html) as shown below to automatically redirect to **Home** page in Django Admin if authenticated and the user is staff and to add **Go to normal login page** and **Go to two factor setup page** buttons:

```
{% "templates/two_factor/core/login.html" %}

{% extends "two_factor/_base_focus.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load two_factor_tags %}

{% block extra_media %}
{% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Add ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %}
<script>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_staff %}
location = "{% url 'admin:index' %}";
{% endif %}
</script>
{% ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Add ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ %}
  {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

...

       </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
  {% ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Add ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ %}
  <hr>
  {% if request.GET.next == "/account/two_factor/setup/" %}
    <a class="btn btn-block btn-success" href="{% url 'two_factor:login' %}">{% trans "Go to normal login page" %}</a>
  {% else %}
    <a class="btn btn-block btn-success" href="{% url 'two_factor:setup' %}">{% trans "Go to two factor setup page" %}</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Add ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now, this is **Login** page:

```
http://localhost:8000/account/login/
```

[image]

```
http://localhost:8000/account/login/?next=/account/two_factor/setup/
```

[image]

And, this is **Account Security** page:

```
http://localhost:8000/account/two_factor/
```

[image]