# Why is it not sensible to store Django templates within their associated apps?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, project-organization

Per the winning answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740436/what-is-the-best-location-to-put-templates-in-django-project) and per everything else I've read on the [interwebs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something), you're most likely going to put Django templates for `mySubAppX` in a folder outside of `mySubAppX` - most commonly `myProject/templates/mySubAppX` where templates is a directory sibling to the actual `mySubAppX` directory where the app is stored.

Why? Especially when you're making sub applications to be modular why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a rule and depends. There is [supporter for the inside-app solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747960/165603) also.

In the centralized-template way, `templates/app/template_name`, locating a template is fast and template names could be as simple as `app/item.html`; you could easily manage/move the whole directory to some place such as memory-disk as well.

On the other hand, the inside-app ways, `app/templates/app_template_name` or `app/templates/app/template_name`, work better for packaged apps. For editing, my colleague found that the inside-app solution is more convenient for developing in Eclipse, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As `okm` said its not a rule. Django always looks first in to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` directories to find the templates, then it fall back to the apps/packages directory to look for templates. That is why it is advised to put the apps template their so that they can quickly be found.

You can still place your templates in your `mySubAppX`.

```
project/apps/mySubAppX/templates
```

And to make it efficient so you can add this path to your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in settings, so that Django first looks there to find the template.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'project/apps/mySubAppX/templates',
    #other apps template directories
)
```