# Where to place my base.html file?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am trying to follow [Django's Template system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/) while using a base.html file, however I am unsure of where to place base.html inside of my project. With namespacing in mind, Django suggests that your templates go inside of your 'project_name/app_name/templates/app_name/' directory. Since I would like to  extend my base.html in multiple apps in my project, where should my base.html reside?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since this is a shared template, place it in the project's `templates` directory:

```
project_name/templates/base.html
```

Also see:

- [What is the best location to put templates in django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740436/what-is-the-best-location-to-put-templates-in-django-project)

Comment: Receiving a "TemplateDoesNotExist at /news/" when trying to extend base.html. I have updated my TEMPLATE_DIRS setting to include "/project_name/templates" and "/news/templates".

My template loader postmordem states
/project_name/templates/base.html (File does not exist)
/news/templates/base.html (File does not exist).

I feel like I missed a step but can't seem to figure it out. Do you have any suggestions on what I may have done wrong? Do I have to adjust my "extends" statement at all?

Comment: @Jimi add the absolute path to the `templates` directory to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting, then use just `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. Should work.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote your answer but thank you so much for the prompt assistance. Absolute paths resolved the error I was receiving.