# Django can't find template directory

Tags: python, django, templates, directory

I know there are many questions similar to this one, but none has solved my problem yet.

Python version: 3.4
Django version: 1.8

I get **TemplateDoesNotExist at /lfstd/** when loading http://127.0.0.1:8000/lfstd/.

system.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
```

lfstd/views.py:

```
def index(request):
[...]
return render(request, 'lfstd/index.html', context_dict)
```

project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^lfstd/', include('lfstd.urls')),
```

lfstd urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from lfstd import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'))
```

Running print on base_dir and template_path, I get:

```
Base dir: C:\Users\Phil\PycharmProjects\TownBuddies
Template path: C:\Users\Phil\PycharmProjects\TownBuddies\templates
```

Which is exactly where my project and template folder is located. However, django doesn't look in that folder for templates. It looks in the following folders:

```
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\lfstd\index.html (File does not exist)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\lfstd\index.html (File does not exist)
```

In fact, if I move my template there, it does find it and it works.

Any help is very appreciated, I'm starting out with Django and completely stuck...

**EDIT:**

I changed *TEMPLATE_DIRS* to *TEMPLATES* but Django still isn't looking in the templates folder:
[image: from the django debug report]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting is deprecated in django 1.8.  You should use the [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) instead:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks load, this is a start. It still doesn't work though, please have a look at my edit.

Comment: Postmortem says that django didn't get template dir setting. It uses the app dirs only. May be you set some other key instaed of `DIRS`?  I updated the answer with the sample setting.

Comment: You were absolutely right. I discovered it moments before your last comment. After reading your answer, I had only renamed TEMPLATE_DIRS to TEMPLATES, and had overlooked the TEMPLATES variable already there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was doing some unit testing with [pytest-django](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-django/) when suddenly I was getting repeated and completely unexpected ** TemplateDoesNotExist** errors.

I found this stackoverflow question while trying to figure out what was going on.

I finally solved the issue by deleting all the `__pycache__` directories. I have since learned that when things suddenly go inexplicably wonky to clear out the `__pycache__` before breaking things by trying to fix them!

I used this script to clear out all the `__pycache__` directories recursively where a module with the following resides:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import shutil

#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import shutil

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(BASE_DIR)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(BASE_DIR):
    for directory in dirs:
        if directory == '__pycache__':
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, directory))
```