# Django Template Loader not reaching app template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mezzanine

According to Django documentation

"Your project’s TEMPLATES setting describes how Django will load and render templates. The default settings file configures a DjangoTemplates backend whose APP_DIRS option is set to True. By convention DjangoTemplates looks for a “templates” subdirectory in each of the INSTALLED_APPS."

My Mezzanine settings.py has this configuration

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

My directory structure is

```
project
    app_name
        templates
            app_name
                index.html
```

But the template loader stops at

```
project
    app_name
        templates
```

As such my app_name template index.html is not reached.  What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to change your template dirs on `setting.py` like this

```
'DIRS': ["templates"],
```

and did your `views.py`  provide specific location of template E.g.

```
return render(request, 'foldername/templatename.html', {})
```

Comment: Any way to make Django recurse to the directories beyond the 'templates' directory?

Comment: Read this [site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740436/what-is-the-best-location-to-put-templates-in-django-project) maybe will help to answer your question, but creating a `templates` directory inside your app directory is ideal to store your app-specific templates.

Answer (score 0):

Then you could reach your template with 'app_name/index.html'